# Sumar datos concretos de un arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

En el siguiente arrayList :

```
Nombre: Producto1, CodProducto: 1, Precio: 10.0

Nombre: Producto2, CodProducto: 2, Precio: 20.0

Nombre: Producto3, CodProducto: 3, Precio: 30.0
```

**¿Cómo puedo sumar los elementos de precio?.**
Quiero obtener el total de la suma de los precios.

Comment: deberias mostrar lo que has intentado hacer y no ha resultado. Cual es el codigo relacionado? que clase estas ocupando para almacenar los datos de un producto?

Answer (score 4):

Asumo que el ArrayList que indicas es de algun Objeto que posee esos campos que mencionas. Una manera de hacerlo seria:

```
double precioTotal = 0;

for(Objeto objeto : arrayListObjeto) {
    precioTotal += objeto.getPrecio();
}

System.out.println(precioTotal);
```

O desde Java 8 usando streams y lambdas:

```
double precioTotal= arrayListObjeto.stream()
      .mapToDouble(o -> o.getPrecio())
      .sum();
System.out.println(precioTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te muestro un ejemplo tomando como base los datos que ya posees:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         Data dato1 = new Data("Producto1",1,10.0);
         Data dato2 = new Data("Producto2",2,20.0);
         Data dato3 = new Data("Producto3",3,30.0);
       ArrayList<Data> arrayList = new ArrayList<Data>();
       arrayList.add(dato1);
       arrayList.add(dato2);
       arrayList.add(dato3);

        Double total = 0.00;
        for (Data data : arrayList) {
           total += data.Precio; 
        }
        System.out.println(total);
     }
}

class Data {
    String Nombre;
    Integer CodProducto;
    Double Precio;

    Data(String nombre,Integer codProducto,Double precio){  
        this.Nombre = nombre;  
        this.CodProducto = codProducto;  
        this.Precio = precio;  
    }  
}
```

[Aqui el ejemplo](http://tpcg.io/jALcoW)

Answer (score 0):

int resultado = productos[0].precio + productos[1].precios;

solo debes escoger los productos que necesitas y sumas sus precios :P